# Is it possible to do async operations in WatchKit Complications?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I've found that doing async operations in watchOS 2 complications has random results. Sometimes the operation completes and the complication updates and sometimes it doesn't. One such example is querying HealthKit.

```
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(start, endDate: toDate, options: [.StrictStartDate, .StrictEndDate])
        let statisticsQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(
            quantityType: quantityType,
            quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
            options: options) { (query, statistics, error) -> Void in
                handler(statistics)
        }
        self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(statisticsQuery)
```

This code will result in a a call to the handler about half the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each complication has a daily time budget. Is it possible you're exceeding it? In this case, the complication might not be updated until the following day.

Comment: Generally, you should be periodically fetching the required data before the complication data source requests it and caching it. This way you already have it when the complication requests it.

Comment: See [Implementing the Data Source Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/CreatingaComplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH10-SW1) in the docs